# Dismiss ProgressDialog But Still Leaks

Tags: android, progressdialog

I get the leaked windows error when I try to finish my activity.

I looked at a lot of similar questions about this and the answer was to use `dismiss()` instead of `hide()`, or dismiss the dialog before calling `finish()`.

I call `dismiss()` then call `finish()` why am I getting a leak?

Here is my `ProgressDialog` code that is in a class extending AsyncTask

```
    public Background(Context c){
        context = c; //the activity's context
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        dialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //do http request
        return "";
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        dialog.dismiss();
        if(request == LOGOUT_REQUEST)
            finish();
        else{
            getResults(document);
        }
    }
```

It worked before, but I believe my code was wrong. I was starting a new activity back to the old activity, instead of just calling finish, which I believe is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dismissing the dialog in the `onPostExecute` method. That method won't run unless the `AsyncTask` has completed. Are you only getting the error when you exit the app with the back button? If so, you should also make sure the dialog is dismissed in the `onDestroy` of your Activity.

Comment: No, the task completes, I don't push back. I put it in the onDestroy just in case and it didn't help.

Comment: I got it to work. Something weird was happening in the `onPostExecute`. I didn't really change anything but its working now. I guess I will come back to it if it pops back up. Your answer is relevant. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Found it, had a method in my `onDestroy` that shouldn't have been there. It was trying to make a new background thread which included the progress dialog.

Comment: how to make it dismiss ondestroy ? Can you show some code , thanks =)